# Tcl/tk How can i know when and which radiobutton is selected?

Tags: radio-button, tcl, tk-toolkit

I've been strugling with what seems to be so trivial =(

I need to know which radiobutton is selected so I may enable and disable my entry.

```
radiobutton .t.r1 -text "Default" -variable reptype -value 0
radiobutton .t.r2 -text "Custom" -variable reptype -value 1
.t.r1 select    

place .t.r1 -x 20 -y 30
place .t.r2 -x 20 -y 50

entry .t.ecustom -width 70 
place .t.ecustom -x 100 -y 50

if { $reptype == 0 } {
    .t.ecustom configure -state normal
} elseif { $reptype == 1 } {
    .t.ecustom configure -state disabled
}
```

This is what i'm tryng, changing some bits here and there, but the result is never what I want, in this example the reptype variable is not recognized.

Comment: `reptype` hasn't been set to a value.   The code needs to be configured like JK's answer so that the radiobutton changes drive the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a trace on the variable, or use the `-command` callback. In your case I suggest using the `-command` callback.

```
set ::reptype 0
radiobutton .t.r1 -text "Default" -variable reptype -value 0 -command entrystate
radiobutton .t.r2 -text "Custom" -variable reptype -value 1 -command entrystate
entry .t.ecustom -state disabled
grid .t.r1
grid .t.r2 .t.ecustom
grid columnconfigure .t 1 -weight 1

proc entrystate {} {
    if {$::reptype} {
        .t.ecustom configure -state normal
    } else {
        .t.ecustom configure -state disabled
    }
}
```

Comment: I might've used `.t.ecustom configure -state [lindex {disabled normal} $::reptype]` as the body of the procedure, but it's the same idea.